# Display a grid view without border columns

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to display a specific number of products in a e-commerce drupal site in the front page.

I would like to use a display as in my theme's demo : http://demo.morethanthemes.com/tophit/

I tried one module for horizontal slideshow but it turned out to have some bugs and another one for responsive grid did not help me fix my problem.

I am now using the original grid view, without pager.

I want to change the column color from grey to white, in order to be my products aligned but not displayed as a table.

Do you know any way to simple display a set of products/nodes horizontal ?
I prefer to use views, because the products probably will change.

Thank you,

Konstantina

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Views Slideshow Module](https://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) to build your slider, it's been the easiest to install and configure in my experience.

As far as changing colors, you are likely going to need to change your theme's CSS, which is not a Drupal specific problem. [This search](https://www.google.ca/#q=css+html&safe=off) should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

The basic views grid display format is not very suitable for a 'tile' layout as it is not responsive, meaning that it will not work very well on mobile phones. Try resizing your browser window to see this.

You have a number of options. For Drupal 7 you could try Views Responsive Grid module https://www.drupal.org/project/views_responsive_grid . This will probably get you where you want to be with the minimum of css theming work.

Your chosen theme uses the Bootstrap framework and therefore a better fit will probably be Views Bootstrap module https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bootstrap - Indeed your theme may already be using this. If this is the case then the answer to your grid questions will be about using the correct Bootstrap classes in your view. This module allows you to do this without diving into css code.

To get more out of your theme, learning about Bootstrap will be time well spent and the following videos may help get you started

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWfYKdCEpOc

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3j7eRunzv4

As Scott Joudry says, when we start asking about colors, css and frameworks we are straying away from asking about Drupal, but given that Bookstrap is well used by the Drupal community I think there is a place for some of your questions here.